# r* tree reinsert

Tags: database, tree, spatial, r-tree

how does the reinsert works? When i select entries to reinsert, i run again insert algorithm?
So reinserted entries can be anywhere in the [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%2a_tree)? 
Or these entries can be only in siblings leafs, in fact, only in the leafs, which have same parent as the leaf from which i reinsert?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with the language `R`?

Comment: I'm guessing no.  Editing to remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They must be inserted **at the same height**.

But other than that, it works the same as an insert. And in fact, you really want to allow reinsertion in other subtrees, if this improves the tree quality.